# Proof of elliptic curves being an abelian group

Tags: proof-writing, abelian-groups, elliptic-curves

What are some simple proofs that the points on an elliptic curve form an abelian group under addition? I am mostly looking for proofs of closure and associativity, since the other three requirements follow immediately from the definitions. Note that I am specifically looking for simpler proofs, since I am only still in high-school, so I have not learned about homomorphisms and isomorphisms and matrices yet. An intuitive 'proof' will also suffice (since again, it's only high-school level). Also, are elliptic curve points always an abelian group under addition? Or only over the rational numbers or over some finite prime field (and not over the reals)? I'm trying to write a paper/essay on elliptic curve cryptography, but I can't get these proofs to work.

Comment: Try this http://math.rice.edu/~friedl/papers/AAELLIPTIC.PDF

Comment: Well, if your level is high school then this proof may be a little too high for you, and the toughest part is always, as far as I know, to prove associativity. All the rest is more or less easy. The paper above runs through some 7 pages of some obtuse mathematics thoug, probably, "easier" than other usual proofs. Be warned, there's no, as far as I know, anything even close to "easy" in these proofs, *though* perhaps showing some picture you can build up a convincing geometric-intuitive proof. Take a peek at some of the books at the end of the above paper.